# It's a yearly task, alright

Tags: code-golf, date

Given a number 1≤n≤365, output the nth day of the year in "Day-numberth Month" format. For example, given 1, you should output "1st January", without "of".

The Gregorian calendar will be used and the program should not account for leap years, so your program should never output "29th February" in any circumstance. Any method can be used, as long as it follows the "Day-numberth Month" format mentioned before. Your program should also output ordinals correctly, meaning it should always output 1st, 2nd, 3rd, should 1, 2 or 3 respectively be the day numbers for any input. Leading spaces or other indentation are allowed.

This is code golf, so the shortest solution by characters wins.

Test cases:

```
1 gives 1st January
2 gives 2nd January
3 gives 3rd January
365 gives 31st December
60 gives 1st March
11 gives 11th January
```

Comment: What is "Day-number Month" format? I'm assuming it's "20th March"? Or is it "20 March"? That makes a pretty big difference, if you need ordinals.

Comment: Also, do you need to force an error message on numbers > 365? Can the program just assume that's invalid input and it won't need to handle that?

Comment: Can we output native Date object that is builtin to our language, without converting it to a string? If we do have to convert it to a string, do we have to output in that exact format?

Comment: I believe input validation is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/16596#16596) in challenges, at least to a point.

Comment: As not everyone is a native English speaker, you may want to add that day numbers 11, 12, and 13 get "th", numbers ending in "1" get "st", "2" get "nd", "3" get "rd", and all other get "th".

Comment: So is it `March 1st` or `1st March`?

Comment: The latter, I messed up.

Comment: Whoa, don't accept answers so quickly. Especially not *wrong* answers!

Comment: Whoops. I guess I'll check every answer and wait for a shorter one.

Comment: This is [14 bytes in Dyalog APL 18.0](https://i.imgur.com/SBmEcx8.png): `'Doo Mmmm'∘⎕DN` but it hasn't been released yet ;-(

Comment: When it releases, tell me.

Comment: You should add at least `11` (11**th** January) and `21` (21**st** January) to the test cases.

Comment: And while you're editing test cases, maybe specify what exactly your test case format is.  A couple of answerers have thought that `123=` was part of the required output. Or simply edit your test cases to read something like: `365` gives `31st December`

Comment: I'm quite surprised this has not been asked before. Good question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>38</del> <del>40</del> <del>30</del> 28 bytes

```php
<?=date("jS F",86399*$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSep2CrYGZgrWBvBxS0TUksSdVQygpWcFPSsTAztrTUAqvRtP7/HwA)

Run with `php -nF` input is from `STDIN`. Example (above script named `y.php`):

```php
$ echo 1|php -nF y.php
1st January
$ echo 2| php -nF y.php
2nd January
$ echo 3| php -nF y.php
3rd January
$ echo 11|php -nF y.php
11th January
$ echo 21|php -nF y.php
21st January
$ echo 60|php -nF y.php
1st March
$ echo 365|php -nF y.php
31st December
```

**Explanation**

Construct an epoch timestamp for the desired day in 1970 (conveniently not a leap year) by multiplying the `day number * number of seconds per day` (86400).  However, this would yield one day higher so instead multiply by `number of seconds in a day - 1` (86399) which for the range of input numbers (1≤n≤365) will result with the timestamp of the end of each correct day. Then just use PHP's built-in date formatting for output.

Comment: why's the `-n` necessary?

Comment: @Ven it might not be in all cases, but just disables any settings in local php.ini that might create inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>115</s> <s>113</s> <s>109</s> 98 bytes

```cs
g=>$"{f=(g=p.AddDays(g-1)).Day}{"tsnr"[f=f%30%20<4?f%10:0]}{"htdd"[f]} {g:MMMM}";DateTime p;int f;
```

Thanks to @someone for saving 9 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY6xCoMwFEX3foWECglWiW1xMMZSkE7tVuhQHMSY9A2mkqSDiN@exjsd7llOb9Pegr/9dF@JWXcj9AfrDGhVy/Bxr3i9R4vkWPEpuwrRdLPFKs0JyQKuC3JWG/SWXMYnGh9pdb7IOKclbYP7OCGCa9doUeUjbEWs6dzwhHGIJgbaRZJ5@TV4Q@A5g@pUFAyShOxeBtxwBz3grQQDIcz/AQ)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I got the modulos out of order, should be fixed now.

Comment: `.code.tio(2,22): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'p'` It appears that the struct thing doesn't work.

Comment: `var g=new DateTime().AddDays(n-1)` works though

Comment: @JAD mistake on my part, fixed

Comment: [110 bytes I think](https://tio.run/##HY6xDoIwFEV3v4I0krShEBB1oBRjJEzqpHEwDoTS@gYKoXUwhG9H8Ez3TPdUxq8MTMVHVyloS43tQausuF9PfNI8w4p3wVGIvPwarP2IUMlVMBttuHTj0N2E6fYg3ShMQtom0lujAVmje/RsXuOA3laI/3QGlVxmRkSCluWlrW/Q1E5HFZt/HUmbicm2x4sAjxikPN7vGHgeWT16sPUZdI2XLgyEsOkH "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @someone Haven't been golfing in a while, but found an even shorter way

Comment: [100 bytes by rearranging stuff to get rid of `return`, braces and a semicolon.](https://tio.run/##FY69CoMwGEX3PoVIhQR/iLU4GGMpSKd2K3QoDpKY9BtMxaSDiM@exjvde85yuUm5AXf7aV6LRfcj8MTYGbRqpGfMKdYcw1UypNiUXYVo@8UgleYYZ75ua2iNnsP3yGRUkOhE6vNFRjmpSOfdxwrhXbcFq6oePltI294OTxiHYKKgbSCTkTr5ndE@gOUU6qIsKcQxPrxmsMMd9ID2Lwgwpu4P "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @someone Got it down to 98. Just one more till I beat the Jelly answer!

Comment: @Embodiment there is a 77-byte Jelly answer there.

Comment: @someone My mistake, I didn't see the other one

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>79 78</s>  77 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 fixing a bug :) <sub>(shouldn't pre-transpose to find index, should post-reverse, but then we can tail rather than head)</sub>
-1 using reflection <sub>(`⁽©ṅB+30_2¦2` -> `⁽0ṗb4+28m0`)</sub>

```
⁽0ṗb4+28m0SRṁRƲœiµṪȮ%30%20«4ị“nḄƲf⁷»s3¤Ṗ,ị“£ṢtẒ⁽ẹ½MḊxɲȧėAṅ ɓaṾ¥D¹ṀẏD8÷ṬØ»Ḳ¤$K
```

A full program which prints the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZkAZv9qZWxsef//4oG9MOG5l2I0KzI4bTBTUuG5gVLGssWTacK14bmqyK4lMzAlMjDCqzThu4vigJxu4biExrJm4oG3wrtzM8Kk4bmWLOG7i@KAnMKj4bmidOG6kuKBveG6ucK9TeG4injJssinxJdB4bmFIMmTYeG5vsKlRMK54bmA4bqPRDjDt@G5rMOYwrvhuLLCpCRL////NDU)**

#### How?

*will update this later...*

```
⁽©ṅB+30_2¦2SRṁRƲZœiµḢȮ%30%20«4ị“nḄƲf⁷»s3¤Ṗ,ị“...»Ḳ¤$K - Main Link: integer, n
⁽©ṅB+30_2¦2SRṁRƲZœi - f(n) to get list of integers, [day, month]
⁽©ṅ                 - compressed literal 2741
   B                - to a list of binary digits -> [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    +30             - add thirty                    [31,30,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
         ¦          - sparse application...
        2           - ...to indices: [2]
       _  2         - ...action: subtract two       [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
               Ʋ    - last four links as a monad - i.e. f(x):
           S        -   sum x                       365
            R       -   range                       [1..365]
              R     -   range x (vectorises)        [[1..31],[1..28],...]
             ṁ      -   mould like                  [[1..31],[32..59],...]
                Z   - transpose                     [[1,32,...],[2,33,...],...]
                 œi - 1st multi-dimensional index of n  -> [day, month]

µḢȮ%30%20«4ị“nḄƲf⁷»s3¤Ṗ,ị“...»Ḳ¤$K - given [day, month] format and print
µ                                  - start a new monadic chain - i.e. f(x=[day, month])
 Ḣ                                 - head -- get the day leaving x as [month])
  Ȯ                                - print it (with no newline) and yield it
   %30                             - modulo by thirty
      %20                          - modulo by twenty
         «4                        - minimum of that and four
                     ¤             - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
            “nḄƲf⁷»                -   dictionary words "standard"+" the" = "standard the"
                   s3              -   split into threes = ["sta","nda","rd ","the"]
           ị                       - index into
                      Ṗ            - remove rightmost character
                               ¤   - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                         “...»     -   dictionary words "January"+" February"+...
                              Ḳ    -   split at spaces = ["January","February",...]
                        ị          - index into (vectorises across [month])
                       ,           - pair                  e.g. ["th", ["February"]]
                                K  - join with spaces           ["th ", "February"]
                                   - print (implicitly smashes)   th February
```

Comment: The "standard the" trick is amazing.

Comment: I agree with _@Ven_, great trick! It also saved a byte in [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181508/52210) in comparison to the compressed string `"thstndrd"` split into parts of size 2 (`.•oθ2(w•2ô`), so thanks. :)

Comment: This has to be one of the longest Jelly programs I have ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 112 bytes

```python
lambda x:str(d:=(t:=gmtime(x*86399)).tm_mday)+'tsnrhtdd'[d%5*(d%30%20<4)::4]+strftime(' %B',t)
from time import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxLDoIwFAD3nqIb0lcwBEQNNLLxGmpMzWuFhH5SXgycvqKznGQmrDR417QhJtPf06TsCxVb5EwRUPZAsn9bGq2GJW/PTdcJUZJ9WlSrKDjNLg6EyG@YnXLArKmyQ3U5CimPj2J7mH/KWXblexI7E71lP8VGG3ykPIU4OgID@qMm8EE7qEQZtUIQG6muvw)

Weirdly enough, I don't have to parenthesize `d:=(t:=gmtime(~-x*86400)`, probably because the interpreter only checks if there are `()` characters around the assignment expression and not that the expression itself is parenthesized.

-2 thanks to [gwaugh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84624/gwaugh).
-5 thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>166</s> 161 bytes

```perl6
{~(.day~(<th st nd rd>[.day%30%20]||'th'),<January February March April May June July August September October November December>[.month-1])}o*+Date.new(1,1,1)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BC4JAFITv/Yp3sbRMXCUvmSBIB6E6dAwPqz4z0FW2tVgy/7qtxoN538xhpkVeeWMtYVnAYfwMupVTOei@KOEpgOXA8@A2ZZpra46d9P1KlCvD9GPKOsolHDHlM5woz0oIW/6oFEuIO4ZKKglhd@9U2RVbgXWKHC6ZaKZ/bl7/IMJsBjVVN0yUW5IY32a9iahAi@FbJ6Y6Y0vG/cIn4IALrrcDzwainB0EgbUslDypHH8)

Hardcodes all the month names, which takes up most of the space. Man, Perl 6 really needs a proper date formatter.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>117</s>  113 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

```javascript
d=>(n=(d=new Date(1,0,d)).getDate())+([,'st','nd','rd'][n%30%20]||'th')+' '+d.toLocaleString('en',{month:'long'})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcu9bsIwFIbhvVfhAWRbfEQ@x/mBVmFqt24dERJRbBKq1K6C1Q4h156iLo/0Du9n89Pc2vH6nbYhOr9c6sXVBxVq5ergf8Vrk7wiGDits86n/9Z6o46QtyQhg3swOnk6hrU1azan@12mXuqNFHLjshTfY9sM/iON19Ap6YPE9BVD6p/lEEMnZ728HAkMixwFSlTYYQ8yIAIxyIJyUAEqQRVoB9qDDfjxMNiCc3ABLsEVeAfewxpYQvmwLE5P2SWOb03bKyfqg2hjuMXBZ0Ps1Hk1uVlsD2I1XZTT81nr5Q8)

#### Commented

```javascript
d =>                     // d = input day
  ( n =                  //
    ( d =                // convert d to
      new Date(1, 0, d)  //   a Date object for the non leap year 1901
    ).getDate()          // save the corresponding day of month into n
  ) + (                  //
    [, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'] // ordinal suffixes
    [n % 30 % 20]        // map { 1, 2, 3, 21, 22, 23, 31 } to { 'st', 'nd', 'rd' }
    || 'th'              // or use 'th' for everything else
  ) + ' ' +              // append a space
  d.toLocaleString(      // convert d to ...
    'en',                // ... the English ...
    { month: 'long' }    // ... month name
  )                      //
```

---

## Without date built-ins, 188 bytes

```javascript
f=(d,m=0)=>d>(k=31-(1115212>>m*2&3))?f(d-k,m+1):d+([,'st','nd','rd'][d%30%20]||'th')+' '+`JanuaryFebruaryMarchAprilMayJuneJulyAugustSeptemberOctoberNovemberDecember`.match(/.[a-z]*/g)[m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZBLb4JAGEX3/RUstMPIBflmBLUNNCZtFya2iy4JCSODj8rD8DCx6m@3tJtzchc3N7nf6qSatN4fW7usdHa/bwJTowhcHoQ6NA@BJNskIk@QCMNiJB4l5y8bU9sHFBbxJ22ZEVjTMrBS96g1iyM9lO5QuPH1ytod4xYzmJUsVdmp@vyeres/r1Sd7hbHep@v1HnZldmyy8@Lbts17Vd2bLNindWfaVv1@qhO//E1S/@dOIVq0505diJl/8Sj8ZZHRXx/jggCEhN48DHFDHOQCyKQAEnQBOSBfNAUNAPNIVyIviMgJMQEwoPwIaYQM4g5pAtJ8Hv6XvzgbKr6TfWr2ghCI63KpsozJ6@2ZjK46Jthh8bg0h/Dbwnn918)

Comment: Fails for 11th,12th,13th of each month

Comment: @ExpiredData Thanks for reporting this. Fixed now.

Comment: Ignore my comment, I made an ID10T error.

Comment: I'm not sure how nodejs handle language tags, but it seems using `0` would work as using `"en"`. And changing to `toLocaleString` would save 4 bytes. [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hcu9bsIwFIbhvVfhAWRbfEQ@x/mBVmFqt24dERJRbBKq1K6C1Q4h156iLo/0Du9n89Pc2vH6nbYhOr9c6sXVBxVq5ergf8Vrk7wiGDits86n/9Z6o46QtyQhg3swOnk6hrU1azan@12mXuqNFHLjshTfY9sM/iON19Apg@krhtQ/yyGGTs56eTkSGBY5CpSosMMeZEAEYpAF5aACVIIq0A60Bxvw42GwBefgAlyCK/AOvIc1sITyYVmcnrJLHN@atldO1AfRxnCLg8@G2KnzanKz2B7Earoop@ez1ssf)

Comment: @tsh It seems that `toLocaleString` is using the system default settings when it's passed an unrecognized string or a numeric value. So, it can be anything. This parameter is basically ineffective on a TIO instance, because [only English locales are installed](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pyc/OTEnVUE38f9/AA) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

## Hack, <s>115</s> <s>59</s> 39 bytes

```php
$x==>date("jS F",mktime(0,0,0,1,$x));
```

Since @gwaugh got to the same solution as mine while I was golfing, I'm posting this in Hack instead :).

Comment: Wow, great minds think alike. :) +1 to you sir!

Comment: @gwaugh haha, I didn't know I could just have a top-level program. I'll edit mine to make it top-level too, and find a way to get a better scor e;-)

Comment: @gwaugh Made mine Hack instead.

Comment: You'll probably want to specify a non-leap year parameter to your `mktime()` call otherwise it will return the wrong output if run on a leap year. (had to do to my answer).

Answer (score 4):

## Smalltalk, 126 bytes

```
d:=Date year:1day:n.k:=m:=d dayOfMonth.10<k&(k<14)and:[k:=0].o:={#st.#nd.#rd}at:k\\10ifAbsent:#th.m asString,o,' ',d monthName
```

Comment: I don't know Smalltalk, but is this correct for `11th,12th,13th`? If I read correctly you integer-divide the day by 10, but that would mean it would result in `11st,12nd,13rd`, unless something else in the code fixes this while I'm unaware of it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You are right. Thanks for calling my attention on this. I'll need to spend some more bytes to fix this.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>141</s> <s>139</s> <s>133</s> <s>124</s>  122 bytes

```cs
a=>{var d=s.AddDays(a-1);int x=d.Day,m=x%30%20;return x+"thstndrd".Substring(m<4?m*2:0,2)+d.ToString(" MMMM");};DateTime s
```

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for faster method of removing 11,12,13th saving 4 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsIwFET3fsWlUEjsg7Y@FqapCMWVrhRcxybVu2gKSSqV4rfHirM8zJlpbNJY9MdBNyVqF1tnUD8qaLkXvJpewoDkNj1IWYu3JSLJKZt7MHKZziTu@BiusrDImFFuMBrGKHBP67Q0Mkgvw/0/SLpyve@WxS6LCxrJ9Npf/jyA85yAsg@rhVNX7BRYzxZtb8jvB3nOEEpYbTcMMIrodDPo1Am1Ii1BOov@Cw)

Comment: Using C# 8, this can be reduced to: 

`a=>{var d=s.AddDays(a-1);int x=d.Day,m=x%30%20;return x+"thstndrd"[(m<4?m*2:0)..2]+$" {d:MMMM}";};DateTime s`

The interactive compiler doesn't seem to support changing its language level to "preview" at this time, though.

Comment: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY3NCoJAGEX3PsUgCTP5g9nPws8xAmlVq4LWkzPWt3CCmTEM8dnN6C4Ph3NrG9cWp2On6wK1i6wzqB8lafgkeDm8hSGS2@QgZSU@lop4xWD2SM9lMpOo5X2wToMsBaNcZzTpQ989rdPSSD@5dPd/kLbFZt8uszyNMhZ6C3945Od5ow8jVMKpK7aKWJjAa16G/h6QrwBJQda7LRAMQzbcDDp1Qq1oQ5ExGKcv)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to add a semi-colon after the `DataTime s`

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>158</strike> 134 bytes

-24 bytes @Nick Kennedy for golfing the 'st', 'nd', 'rd', & 'th'. Thanks!

```r
f=format;paste0(a<-as.double(f(d<-as.Date(scan(,''),'%j'),'%e')),`if`((a-1)%%10>2|a%/%10==1,'th',c("st","nd","rd")[a%%10]),f(d,' %B'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEWvIoEwMzDVRldi40K8hQgdmwQV20oSd949xm4e/8PjxVKCDXMcJR/ekrJvUbpG0trNn9vLY0C33LNkj2mQCRmAGPRzoQci7h@hR5TGkNamPW6/ojd1WGsY8h14QJWyYjW5iugUXeQvXolrnWGlT7VS9rvyAw)

Comment: How about https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEWvIoEwMzDVRldi40K8hQgdmwQV20oSd949xm4e/8PjxVKCDXMcJR/ekrJvUbpG0trNn9vLY0C33LNkj2mQCRmAGPRzoQci7h@hR5TGkNamPW6/ojd1WGsY8h14QJWyYjW5iugUXeQvXolrnWGlT7VS9rvyAw for 134 bytes

Comment: Yes, I need to learn `\`if\`` better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>81</s> <s>79</s> <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> 69 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•ΘÏF•ºS₂+.¥-D0›©ÏθDT‰ć≠*4šß„—ÃŠØ3ôsè¨ð”……‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í”#®OèJ
```

-9 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.
-1 byte thanks to @JonathanAllan's `standard the` trick for `th,st,nd,rd`, which he used in [his Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181524/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiczMO97sB6UO7gh81NWnrHVqq62LwqGHXoZWH@8/tcAl51LDhSPujzgVaJkcXHp7/qGHeo4Yph5uPLjg8w/jwluLDKw6tOLzhUcPcRw3LwGjWYSCxEKgJyDu85FHDgsPrHzWtObQfxO0GEatAYi0gFkjD4R4Q0Qs0QPnQOv/DK7z@/zc3BAA) or [verify all possible test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9sZurqZ6@k8KhtkoKSvd//Rw2Lzs043O8GpA/tCn7U1KStd2iprovBo4Zdh1Ye7j@3wyXkUcOGI@2POhdomRxdeHj@o4Z5jxqmHG4@uuDwDOPDW4oPrzi04vCGRw1zHzUsA6NZh4HEQqAmIO/wkkcNCw6vf9S05tB@ELcbRKwCibWAWCANh3tARC/QAOVD6/wPr/D6r/MfAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
•ΘÏF•        # Push compressed integer 5254545
     º       # Mirror it vertically: 52545455454525
      S      # Converted to a list of digits: [5,2,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,2,5]
       ₂+    # And 26 to each: [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,28,31]
             # (the additional trailing 28,31 won't cause any issues)
.¥           # Undelta this list (with automatic leading 0):
             #  [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365,393,424]
  -          # Subtract each from the (implicit) input-integer
   D0›       # Duplicate the list, and check for each if it's positive (> 0)
      ©      # Store the resulting list in the register (without popping)
       Ï     # Only leave the values at those truthy indices
        θ    # And get the last value from the list, which is our day
D            # Duplicate this day
 T‰          # Take the divmod-10 of this day: [day//10, day%10]
   ć         # Extract the head; pop and push the remainder-list and head: [day%10], day//10
    ≠        # Check whether the day//10 is NOT 1 (0 if day//10 == 1; 1 otherwise)
     *       # Multiply that by the [day%10] value
      4š     # Prepend a 4 to this list
        ß    # Pop and push the minimum of the two (so the result is one of [0,1,2,3,4],
             # where the values are mapped like this: 1..3→1..3; 4..9→4; 10..19→0; 20..23→0..3; 24..29→4; 30,31→0,1)
 …thŠØ       # Push dictionary string "th standards"
      3ô     # Split it into parts of size 3: ["th ","sta","nda","rds"]
        sè   # Swap and index the integer into this list (4 wraps around to index 0)
          ¨  # And remove the trailing character from this string
ð            # Push a space " "
”……‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í”
             # Push dictionary string "December January February March April May June July August September October November"
 #           # Split on spaces
  ®          # Push the list of truthy/falsey values from the register again
   O         # Get the amount of truthy values by taking the sum
    è        # Use that to index into the string-list of months (12 wraps around to index 0)
J            # Join everything on the stack together to a single string
             # (and output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why:

- (section *How to use the dictionary?*) `”……‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í”` is `"December January February March April May June July August September October November"`
- (section *How to use the dictionary?*) `…thŠØ` is `"th standards"`
- (section *How to compress large integers?*) `•ΘÏF•` is `5254545`

Comment: -2 bytes by using 5в28+ for compression: [TIO](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw2zDi971LDwUcOGRw3LDi951LDg8PpHTWsO7Qdxu0HEKpBYC4i1DET0gIheIAFGc5U9HzUscs53TAZSphc2GVlon9vur3toZYr/4RWHNxxa55JyuN/O8@jCcztcjA1UjQxUXUweNezU0gMqzz@3w0ijHMgwOryl@PAKr///zQ0B)

Comment: @Grimy Thanks! Too bad `•!₆%ζ3•S` and `•CoAc•5в` are the same amount of bytes. Almost thought I could save another byte by using a compressed integer instead of integer list. :)

Comment: Using S is a good idea, -1 byte again: [TIO](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw2zDi971LDwUcOGRw3LDi951LDg8PpHTWsO7Qdxu0HEKpBYC4i1DET0gIheIAFGc5U9HzUscj3cbX54Mkh@UfCjpibtc9v9dQ@tTPE/vOLwhkPrXFIO99t5Hl14boeLsYGqkYGqi8mjhp1aekDV@ed2GGmUAxlGh7cUH17h9f@/uSEA)

Comment: Further -3 bytes by using ``T‰`s<Ā*`` for the ordinal suffix: [TIO](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw2zDi971LDwUcOGRw3LDi951LDg8PpHTWsO7Qdxu0HEKpBYC4i1DET0gIheIAFGc5U9HzUscj3cbX54Mkh@UfCjpibtc9v9dQ@tTPE/vOLwhkPrXFIO99t5Hl14bodLCNCehGKbIw1aekC1@ed2GGmUAxlGh7cUH17h9f@/uSEA)

Comment: @Grimy Thanks for the -1 byte for `•EË7Óæ•S₂+`, but your -3 golf doesn't work unfortunately. Indexing automatically wraps around in 05AB1E, so the `5st,6nd,7rd,25st,26nd,27rd,29st` will be wrong. PS: if it would have worked, `<Ā` could have been `≠` for an additional -1. :)

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9sZurqZ6@koGunoGTv9/9RwyLXw93mhycfXgZkBj9qatI@t91f1yXl0MrD/XZ@Rxee2@FibKBqZKBq8qhh1uH5jxrmPWpYcGjpo6Y1QGR8eMvhxuLDKw6tOLzhUcNckAqgMQsfNQB5yw4vAao8vB6o7NB@ELcbRKwCibWAWMtARA@I6AUSYDRX@dA6/8MrvP7r/AcA)

Comment: [-1 again](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMi18Pd5ocnH14GZAY/amrSPrfdX9cl5dDKw/12nkcXntvhYmygamSgavKoYdbh@Y8a5j1qmHK4@eiCwzOMD28pPrzi0IrDGx41zAXJAo1Y@KgByFt2eMmjhgWH1z9qWnNoP4jbDSJWgcRaQKxlIKIHRPQCCTCaq3xonf/hFV7//xsbAgA) (using "th standards" instead of "standard the" removes the need for `Á`).

Comment: @Grimy Ah, `standards` instead of `standard`. Dangit, why didn't I think of that myself.. I had tried `…th†¥` for `"th standard"`, but it of course gave a problem removing the last character of the `rd`. Can't believe I haven't thought of checking if `standards` is in the dictionary.. And hmm, didn't even knew `th` was in the dictionary either..

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMiZ73DGw9POtIIZAY/amrS1ju0VNfFJuXQysP953a4GBuoGhmomjxqmHV4/qOGeY8aphxuPrrg8Azjw1uKD684tOLwhkcNcx81LAOjWYeBxMJHDUCxZYeXPGpYcHj9o6Y1h/aDuN0gYhVIrAXEAmk43AMieoEGKB9a5394hdf//8YmAA). Turns out undelta is a built-in (`.¥`), which saves some work.

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9sZurqZ6@koGunoGTv9/9Rw6JzMw73uwHpQ7uCHzU1aesdWqrrYvCoYdehlYf7z@1wMTZQNTJQNXnUMOvw/EcN8x41TDncfHTB4RnGh7cUH15xaMXhDY8a5j5qWAZGsw4DiYWPGoBiyw4vedSw4PD6R01rDu0HcbtBxCqQWAuIBdJwuAdE9AINUD60zv/wCq//Ov8B) (`•C.ñÒā•` to `•ΘÏF•º`, the extra digits don't matter)

Comment: @Grimy Oh, that's a nice one. And you just keep on golfing, don't you? :D

Comment: `30%20%4‚` -> [`T‰ć≠*4š`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9sZurqZ6@koGunoGTv9/9Rw6JzMw73uwHpQ7uCHzU1aesdWqrrYvCoYdehlYf7z@1wCXnUsOFI@6POBVomRxcenv@oYd6jhimHm48uODzD@PCW4sMrDq04vOFRw9xHDcvAaNZhILEQqAnIO7zkUcOCw@sfNa05tB/E7QYRq0BiLSAWSMPhHhDRCzRA@dA6/8MrvP7r/AcA) for -1.

Comment: @Grimmy Of course he's still not done. ;p Thanks! Nice alternative for the mapping to 0..4.

Answer (score 3):

## MySQL, <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAKEDATE(1,n),"%D %M")
```

1901 can be replaced with any year that was/is not a leap year.

Edit: saved two bytes by removing spaces and another three bytes by changing the year to 1, thanks to [@Embodyment of Ignorance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84206/embodiment-of-ignorance).

Comment: Can you remove the spaces between `1901, n` and the string?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance yes I can, thanks!

Comment: Also, why not replace 1901 with a year like 1? 1 isn't a leap year, and it's 3 bytes shorter

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance done and done :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>115</s> <s>114</s> <s>101</s> 97 bytes

```
%30%20¹0<?4Ḥ+Ø½ị“thstndrd”ṭ
“5<Ḟ’b4+28ÄŻ_@µ>0T,>0$ƇZṪµ1ịị“£ṢtẒ⁽ẹ½MḊxɲȧėAṅ ɓaṾ¥D¹ṀẏD8÷ṬØ»Ḳ¤,2ịÇƊṚK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/V2EDVyODQTgMbe5OHO5ZoH55xaO/D3d2PGuaUZBSX5KUUpTxqmPtw51ouoIipzcMd8x41zEwy0TayONxydHe8w6GtdgYhOnYGKsfaox7uXHVoqyFQM0T/ocUPdy4qebhr0qPGvQ937Ty01/fhjq6Kk5tOLD8y3fHhzlaFk5MTH@7cd2ipy6GdD3c2PNzV72JxePvDnWuATtj9cMemQ0t0jIAmHW4/1vVw5yzv/8ZmpkE6QHN17YAu0gEKb3rUtCbyPwA)

Long by Jelly standards, but done from first principles.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving 13 bytes through better understanding of string compression.

Comment: `“£ṢtẒ⁽ẹ½MḊxɲȧėAṅ ɓaṾ¥D¹ṀẏD8÷ṬØ»Ḳ¤` would save 13 (Compress.dictionary looks for a leading space and has special handling for it).

Answer (score 2):

## Shell + coreutils, <s>112</s> 90 bytes

```bash
date -d0-12-31\ $1day +%-dth\ %B|sed 's/1th/1st/;s/2th/2nd/;s/3th/3rd/;s/\(1.\).. /\1th /'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxCsMgFEbh3af4h4S0FDVXaZZsfY2YwXIFCyGBKJSC725tt4/DefoU6zu@toAzeMaGUrAs6Das6ww@kEKGlC1U9jlA8ijJSEsOHbH/4NZLztGhf5QUGEPSlKOmlPWctGk0O/9oG@35p7uQcleloF17oYfKxx4qCSOssNNdTKMg@gI) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 22 bytes thanks to @NahuelFouilleul. Explanation:

```bash
date -d0-12-31\ $1day
```

Calculate the number of day(s) after the first day preceding a non-leap year. (Sadly you can't do relative date calculations from `@-1`.)

```bash
+%-dth\ %B|sed
```

Output the day of month (without leading zero), `th`, and the full month name.

```bash
's/1th/1st/;s/2th/2nd/;s/3th/3rd/;
```

Fix up `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, `21st`, `22nd`, `23rd` and `31st`.

```bash
s/\(1.\).. /\1th /'
```

Restore `11th` to `13th`.

Comment: i saw this answer after mine, could save [18bytes](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEbhfU7xL1qqSBonwULpzms0XUQmEKFY6ARE6N1jdPfxeI8gqbzTc43YY2CsOA7MM5oVyzKBN0jM0LqGwiFHaKZxGDVZ7cijIQ4fwaXVnJNHez8kMjoxlJMhyWYSYyvti390lW7/05@o9@e@h/H1hekKb69YSFnllBtuargqoi8) using one sed command, also `s` in `days` can be removed, and `19` in `1969`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul That last one uses a Bash-ism so should be posted as a separate answer, but thanks for the other tips!

Answer (score 2):

## bash, <s>82</s> 80 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only

```
a=(th st nd rd);set `printf "%(%e %B)T" $[$1*86399]`;echo $1${a[$1%30%20]-th} $2
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HclNCsMgEAXgfU8xBAUNFPwhEgnZ9AzdlUBso5hNWqK7kLNbJ4v3eN/M26VYAuNHcSPLEVKGbYF94UPyGebfvm45QEMZ9UAf/NkAeRHZ9kZbO82D/8QvEEkOV69UC6rEdM/xBKLKeQsga1SNxo2QKIlU1w@prq/FJWp1PRbSILXpyh8)

## bash +GNU date, 77 bytes

```
a=(th st nd rd);set `date -d@$[$1*86399] +%e\ %B`;echo $1${a[$1%30%20]-th} $2
```

Comment: [80?](https://tio.run/##HclBCsMgEAXQfU8xBAUNFEYlkhKy6Rm6K4HYRrGbtER3IWe3Thb/89/My6VYgpB7caPIEVKGdYFtkUPyGebf9llzgIYL7oHf5aMB9mSq7a1BnObBv@MXmGK7q1dukGucrjkewHQ5LgFUja4xtAmKpIj6/BH1@b3RwlpdT0W0RGO78gc)

Comment: @ASCII-only, yes subtracting 100s for each day, 100*365 = 36500s which is less than one day (86400), works also with 86399 (subtract 1s by day)

Comment: :/ still looks really long but haven't found a better way yet

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <s>118</s> <s>103</s> 86 bytes

```
=day(A1+1)&mid("stndrdth",min(7,1+2*mod(mod(day(A1+1)-1,30),20)),2)&text(A1+1," mmmm")
```

I can't edit [my comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181469/30134) so, here's a working version of the Google Sheets code.

[Try it Online!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/161NlGfTcky849Ye0A3qLxoaSF8ic2UvBiBQ9yX-ahsg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 235 chars, 470 bytes

```
{k←↑⍸0<w←+\v←(1-⍵),(12⍴28)+13561787⊤⍨12⍴4⋄k<2:¯1⋄d←1+v[k]-w[k]⋄(⍕d),({d∊11..13:'th'⋄1=10∣d:'st'⋄2=10∣d:'nd'⋄3=10∣d:'rd'⋄'th'}),' ',(k-1)⊃(m≠' ')⊂m←'January February March April May June July August September October November December'}
```

13561787 is the number that in base 4 can be summed to (12⍴28) for obtain the lenght of each month...
test:

```
  f←{k←↑⍸0<w←+\v←(1-⍵),(12⍴28)+13561787⊤⍨12⍴4⋄k<2:¯1⋄d←1+v[k]-w[k]⋄(⍕d),({d∊11..13:'th'⋄1=10∣d:'st'⋄2=10∣d:'nd'⋄3=10∣d:'rd'⋄'th'}),' ',(k-1)⊃(m≠' ')⊂m←'January February March April May June July August September October November December'}     
  ⊃f¨1 2 3 365 60 11
1st January  
2nd January  
3rd January  
31st December
1st March    
11th January
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 124 bytes

```
func[n][d: 1-1-1 + n - 1[rejoin[d/4 either 5 > t: d/4 % 30 % 20[pick[th st nd rd]t + 1]['th]]pick system/locale/months d/3]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcy/DoIwEAbwnaf4FuNgCC0IA4MP4drcYGhJq1BIew4@fS2DYC65/HJ/vmB0uhutqBj7NL79oDwp3UOWuXCBRwmpgnkuzitdXWEcWxPQ4gbusU1OaERutVCrG16KLSLDawRNnBMkqTNbom2J@Ils5mpahsdkqnnxbGMOaYjSGpxnjJDFT/Wu5lDX7u7ETnl8tX/HIn0B)

Adds `n` - 1 days to 1-1-1 (1-Jan-2001) to form a date, than uses Arnauld's method to index into month suffixes. Too bad [Red](http://www.red-lang.org) is 1-indexed, this requires additional tweaking. The good thing is that [Red](http://www.red-lang.org) knows the names of the months :)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>174</s> 155 bytes

```c
i;char a[99],*b="thstndrd";f(long x){x--;x*=86400;strftime(a,98,"%d   %B\0",gmtime(&x));i=*a==49?0:a[1]-48;a[2]=b[i=i>3?0:i*2];a[3]=b[++i];x=*a==48?a+1:a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7dioMwFITv8xQHly5R46LVLdo0FvY1bC5Sfw/UtMQUhNJnt9G9m/mYga@O@rpevlDXt2fTniyO7c9QLsjrQRlQVVFIFlyFZ4fJ6sY0Hu/o7a57mP3XHEV8DkR@yOKYT9Z065sqVuTM2zUAsPu7xB7rx41/z77PUQRKiKw4x0dVJTLKcq6qvRTXCgWWqcMY7KVj6crCECWf/y/5WYXJUfH3QlBbGBVq6sNrK8gJ6e6Gokg4IJwEpIdfl8JwXcDDuFFHNydROq3poj0GyKCj6KTImxDT2qfREG9l@QA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ṡ`, 81 bytes

```
kṁ¦Ṫ0p-'0>;:L`ƛǓ ⟇∩ ∨₄ ∨⋏ λ√ ∨ɾ ∨∑ ⟇τ ∨₆ ∨Þ ∨∞ ⟑√`⌈$i$t:t:4<[` ∨ǐ`3/vḢȮ‹i|‛th]$_+
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%A1&code=k%E1%B9%81%C2%A6%E1%B9%AA0p-%270%3E%3B%3AL%60%C6%9B%C7%93%20%E2%9F%87%E2%88%A9%20%E2%88%A8%E2%82%84%20%E2%88%A8%E2%8B%8F%20%CE%BB%E2%88%9A%20%E2%88%A8%C9%BE%20%E2%88%A8%E2%88%91%20%E2%9F%87%CF%84%20%E2%88%A8%E2%82%86%20%E2%88%A8%C3%9E%20%E2%88%A8%E2%88%9E%20%E2%9F%91%E2%88%9A%60%E2%8C%88%24i%24t%3At%3A4%3C%5B%60%20%E2%88%A8%C7%90%603%2Fv%E1%B8%A2%C8%AE%E2%80%B9i%7C%E2%80%9Bth%5D%24_%2B&inputs=144&header=&footer=)
What a mess.

```
kṁ                                                # List of month lengths
  ¦                                               # Cumulative sums
   Ṫ0p                                            # Pop off the last and prepend a 0
      -                                           # Subtract from input
       '0>;                                       # Filter by positive
           :L                                     # Duplicate and get length
             `...`⌈$i                             # Index into list of month names
                     $t:t                         # Get the last digit
                         :4<[                     # If it's less than 4 then...
                             `...`                # Push ' standard'
                                  3/              # Split into 3
                                    vḢ            # Lop off the first char of each
                                      Ȯ‹i         # Index the number into this
                                         |   ]    # Else
                                          ‛th     # Push 'th'
                                              $_+ # Swap, pop and concatenate
                                                  # (ṡ flag) join stack by spaces
```